BupaR performance by group
I am working on my hospital data. Processes of outpatient operation center. Details are here:1: friendly link.
I can produce a process-map:

Using process_matrix(performance()) I can produce a tibble:

Now I want to get a tibble of performance grouped by operating procedures "ops_5"
log %>% group_by(ops_5) %>% process_matrix(performance) 

gives me the same result as above, without grouping.
I want a performance tibble grouped by ops_5.

Seems that there is no  solution in bupaR at the moment. So I solved my problem with a loop.
ops_5 <- ev_h |> filter(!is.na(ops_5)) |> distinct(ops_5) |> pull(ops_5)

proc_matrix_df <- tibble()
for (i in ops_5) {
  x <- ev_h |> filter(ops_5 == i) |> process_matrix(performance()) 
  x <- x |> mutate(ops_5 = i) 
    proc_matrix_df <- bind_rows(proc_matrix_df,x)
}

